# What are viable roles for Leona besides support?

Tags: league-of-legends

Leona works best as a support in the current metagame, but can she be played in other roles such as an AP mid or jungler?

She has great CC and decent magical damage, can these aspects be capitalized on to fill any other roles on a team? If so what sort of build would be optimal considering runes, masteries, and items?

Comment: Once the new patch goes through if the roaming meta picks up she would be a great roamer

Answer (score 3):

Almost every champion in League of legends can play every role.

**BUT** they are not viable in all those roles.

> What can Leona do?

Leona is GREAT for tank and GREAT Support roles. You can make a huge difference in the game if you are playing one of those two roles as Leona.

> Can she Jungle or AP Carry?

Yes she can. But she shouldn't be doing it.

I'll not make too much enforce in showing you the right way to do the Jungle or the AP. But here some information any way =)

How to Jungle as Leona (This is a little out of date, but gives you the general idea)

Compilation of AP Leona

> But why this is not a good idea?

She does an amazing damage? YES She does, and if you play Leona as an AP, she will wreak havoc, if you play her as jungle you will clear and gank really fine, even as an AD carry Leona. **But**, she is not mastered this way, because she loses for others AP like Annie and Brand for example. so is better you play AP Brand, and play Support/Tank Leona for real and play for fun AP Leona.

Here good guide for [tank leona](http://solomid.net/guides.php?g=3056) e for [support leona](http://solomid.net/guides.php?g=8323).

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I played Leona myself as a jungler (I'm a jungler) and I was fairly dissapointed. The ganks are not bad but she clears the jungle harder than you might think.

Besides supporting, Leona is a decent solotop champion, which counters some champions but gets countered hard by many others.

Answer (score 1):

She doesnt jungle fast enough to keep up in levels. But  if she could proc her own passive she would become a viable jungle.She can't herself justify in the jungle.

Answer (score 0):

ap mid: probably not. she's melee with rather low base damages, so she's easily harassed even by the autoattacks of enemy mids.

jungler: amazing ganks, terrible clear times. if she could proc her own sunlight maybe she could do it, but as it is, she'll be very very slow in the jungle. it'll also require constant spamming of abilities, and you'll go oom quickly without blue buff (which you'd like to be able to give to mid after the first one).

top: probably the most possible. melee and tanky is more at home here, but she lacks sustain - can probably be remedied with a philo stone and such. still, she'll probably be pushed out of lane pretty easily.

if you're good, im sure you can make leona work in any lane. but she's far from optimal in every role other than an aggressive support. her combo puts her on top of the enemy, which is perfect for locking them down while a partner safely attacks, but is absolutely terrible for solo lanes when you are trying to trade damage and disengage.